# Which property to use in HttpRequestBase Request

Tags: c#

Link:

`http://localhost:xxxxx/DailySummaries/Index/6`

Is there a property of `Request` or something else to only pull the '6' off of the URL and put into variable, and not the whole URL such as using AbsolutePath, etc?

UPDATE:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "xxxxxx", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: try `Regex.Match(Request.AbsolutePath,@'\d+$')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is matched as part of the `RouteData`.

Normally, if you're using ASP.NET MVC or WebApi, from a Controller you can simply call `RouteData.Values["id"]` to get the value.

Comment: I am using this *id* in this manner: `<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary top-margin" value="Clear Search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "DailySummaries", new { id = /*problem here*/ , area = "" })'" />`  How do I declare the RouteData.Values in cshtml?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid you can use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]`